# Can I host multiple sites on a single Linode server a la Dreamhost?

Tags: linode

I currently have Dreamhost, which is nice because I can host multiple domains. Is it possible to host multiple domains on a single Linode virtual host, or would I be limited 1:1 (1 virtual host : 1 domain)?

To make more clear (hopefully):

Let's say (in a bad example) I owned www.google.com and www.facebook.com, as is. The former is a search engine, the other is a social network. Could I host them both on a single linode virtual server and have them work like they should?

Answer (score 6):

You can point as many domains as you like to a single IP address; the VPS has nothing to do with this unless you want SSL.

Comment: i don't think i asked the right question. i'll rewrite it. let's say (in a bad example) I owned www.google.com and www.facebook.com, as is. the former is a search engine, the other is a social network. could I host them both on a single linode virtual server?

Comment: If you configure the web server properly, sure.

Comment: You have full root access, you can do whatever you want :)

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely.  The VPS emulates the hardware of a server.  What you install on that is up to you.  Handling multiple domains is a fairly common webserver function.

What you want to look into is something like Apache2's VirtualHost configuration.  You can find some basic setup details (tailored for an Ubuntu 10.04 installation on Linode) here:

http://library.linode.com/lamp-guides/ubuntu-10.04-lucid

In particular the section on configuring name-based virtual hosts.